# check the presence of a child node recursively in a tree

Tags: python, tree, nodes

I have created a tree object in python using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re,sys,codecs

neg_markers_en=[u'not',u"napt",u'no',u'nobody',u'none',u'never']

class Node:
    def __init__(self,name=None,parent=None,sentence_number=0):
        self.name=name
        self.next=list()
        self.parent=parent
        self.depth=0
        self.n_of_neg=0
        self.subordinate=None
        self.foo=None

def print_node(self):
    print self.name,'contains',[(x.name,x.depth,x.foo) for x in self.next]
    for x in self.next:
        x.print_node()

def get_negation(self):


    for x in self.next:
        if x.n_of_neg!=0:
            print unicode(x.depth)+u' |||',
            try:
                x.look_for_parent_vp()
            except: print 'not in a VP',
            try:
                x.look_for_parent_sent()
            except: print '***'
        x.get_negation()


def look_for_parent_vp(self):

    if self.parent.name=='VP':
        self.parent.print_nont()
    else:
        self.parent.look_for_parent_vp()

def look_for_parent_sent(self):

    if self.parent.name=='S' or self.parent.name=='SBAR':
        #This is to send out to a text file, along with what it covers
        print '||| '+ self.parent.name,
        try:
            self.parent.check_subordinate()
            self.parent.print_nont()
            print '\n'
        except:
            print u'no sub |||',
            self.parent.print_nont()
            print '\n'
    elif self.parent=='None': print 'root |||'
    else:
        self.parent.look_for_parent_sent()


def print_nont(self):

    for x in self.next:
        if x.next==[]:
            print unicode(x.name),
        else: x.print_nont()


def mark_subordinate(self):

    for x in self.next:
        if x.name=='SBAR':
            x.subordinate='sub'
        else: x.subordinate='main'
        x.mark_subordinate()

def check_subordinate(self):

    if self.subordinate=='sub':
        print u'sub |||',
    else:
        self.parent.check_subordinate()


def create_tree(tree):

    #replace "n't" with 'napt' so to avoid errors in splitting
    tree=tree.replace("n't",'napt')
    lista=filter(lambda x: x!=' ',re.findall(r"\w+|\W",tree))

    start_node=Node(name='*NULL*')
    current_node=start_node

    for i in range(len(lista)-1):
        if lista[i]=='(':
            next_node=Node()
            next_node.parent=current_node
            next_node.depth=current_node.depth+1
            current_node.next.append(next_node)
            current_node=next_node
        elif lista[i]==')':
            current_node=current_node.parent
        else:
            if lista[i-1]=='(' or lista[i-1]==')':
                current_node.name=lista[i]
            else:
                next_node=Node()
                next_node.name=lista[i]
                next_node.parent=current_node
                #marks the depth of the node
                next_node.depth=current_node.depth+1
                if lista[i] in neg_markers_en:
                    current_node.n_of_neg+=1
                current_node.next.append(next_node)


return start_node
```

Now all the nodes are linked so that the children nodes of a parent node are appended to a list and each one of these child nodes are referred back to their parent through the instance parent.
I have the following problem:
For each node whose name is 'S' or 'SBAR' (let's call it `node_to_check`), I have to look if any of its children node's name is either 'S' or 'SBAR'; if this is **NOT** the case I want to transform `.foo` attribute of the `node_to_check` into 'atom'.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
def find_node_to_check(self):
    for next in self.next:
        if next.name == 'S' or next.name == 'SBAR':
        is_present = check_children(next)
        if is_present == 'no':
            find_node_to_check(next)
        else:
            self.foo = 'atom'

def check_children(self):
    for next in self.next:
        # is this way of returning correct?
        if next.name == 'S' or next.name == 'SBAR':
            return 'no'
        else:
            check_sents(next)
            return 'yes'
```

I included in my question also the code that I have written so far. A tree structure is created in the function create_tree(tree); the input tree is a bracketed notation from the Stanford Parser.

Comment: do you have to do this with the string or are you allowed to just use the tree?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Are you dealing with existing code or is this your design for a new tree?

Comment: this is design for a new tree.
I have not tried anything I cannot come up with anything reasonable.

Comment: Until you know what operations you want to perform on the tree, you are missing the critical information which will guide your design.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Even with the updates, I don't understand what you are asking. What's wrong with the code you were thinking of using? Does it not work in some way, and if so, what's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to design a novel class, knowing what you need it to do informs how you construct it. Stubbing works well here, for example:

```
class Node:
   """A vertex of an n-adic tree"""

   def __init__(self, name):
       """since you used sentence, I assumed n-adic
          but that may be wrong and then you might want
          left and right children instead of a list or dictionary
          of children"""
       pass

   def append_children(self, children):
       """adds a sequence of child Nodes to self"""
       pass

   def create_child(self, name):
       """creates a new Named node and adds it as a child"""
       pass

   def delete_child(self, name):
       """deletes a named child from self or throws exception"""
       pass
```

And so on. Do children need to be ordered? Do you ever need to delete a node (and descendants)? Would you be able to pre-build a list of children or would you have to do it one at a time. Do you really want to store the fact that a Node is terminal (that's redundant) or do you want `is_terminal()` to return `children is None`?